# No matter which component I update from, only the first component values are updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spK8dGGaczk)

As you can see only first component get updated but the other component stay still. When i go to movie page and rate the movie and go back to page that i showed you in the above video i can get the rate but i cant updated it. Although I tried to solve it, I did not get any results, can you help?

Edit: I moved all states and functions to parent class but it didn't helped.

MovieCard Component

```
function MovieCard(props) {

    const url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + props.movie.poster_path;

    return (
        <div className={style.container}>
            <div className={style.imageContainer}>
                <img loading="lazy" className={style.image} src={url} />
            </div>
            <div className={style.cardDetail}>
                <Link reloadDocument style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit", }} to={"/detail/" + props.movie.id}> <p className={style.title}> {props.movie.title} </p> </Link>
                <p className={style.detail}>{props.movie.overview}</p>
                <StarCard movie={props.movie} />
                <Genre genres={props.movie.genre_ids} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

StarCard Component

```
function StarCard({ movie }) {
    // function StarCard({ lists, movie }) {

    const [lists, setLists] = useState(null);
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
    const [ratedValue, setRatedValue] = useState(null);
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {

            try {
                const ratedValue = await GetRating({ user_id: user._id, movie_id: movie.id });
                setRatedValue(ratedValue);
            } catch (err) {

            }


            const listsData = await fetchLists(user._id);
            setLists(listsData);

        })();

    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <button
                type="button"
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#exampleModal"
                style={{ background: "inherit", border: "none" }}
                onClick={() => {
                    setRating(ratedValue);
                }}>
                {ratedValue ? <p className={styles.ratingBtnTxt}>{ratedValue}/10</p> : (<BsStar size="35" />)}
            </button>

            {/* <!-- Modal --> */}
            <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered " role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className={"modal-header " + styles.container}>
                            <h5 className={"modal-title " + styles.modalRatingTxt} id="exampleModalLabel">{rating ? rating : "Puanla"}</h5>
                            {/* <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button> */}
                        </div>
                        <div className={"modal-body " + styles.container}>
                            {
                                [...Array(10)].map((star, i) => {

                                    const ratingValue = i + 1;

                                    return (
                                        <label key={i}>
                                            <input
                                                className={styles.starInput}
                                                type="radio"
                                                name="rating"
                                                value={ratingValue}
                                                onClick={() => setRating(ratingValue)}
                                            />

                                            <BsStarFill
                                                size="35"
                                                className={styles.star}
                                                color={ratingValue <= (hover || rating) ? "#ffc107" : "#e4e5e9"}
                                                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(ratingValue)}
                                                onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
                                            />
                                        </label>
                                    );
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div className={"modal-footer " + styles.container}>
                            {(ratedValue || rating) && (<button
                                type="button"
                                className="btn btn-danger"
                                data-dismiss="modal"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    DeleteRating({ user_id: user._id, movie_id: movie.id });
                                    RemoveFromList(lists[1]._id, movie);
                                    setRating(null);
                                    setRatedValue(null);
                                }}>
                                Remove Rating
                            </button>)}

                            {/* <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => setRating(null)}>Remove Rating</button> */}

                            <button
                                type="button"
                                className="btn btn-secondary"
                                data-dismiss="modal">
                                Close
                            </button>

                            {rating && (<button
                                type="button"
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                data-dismiss="modal"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    AddToList(lists[1]._id, movie);
                                    addRating({ user_id: user._id, movie_id: movie.id, ratingValue: rating });
                                    setRatedValue(rating);
                                }}>
                                Save changes
                            </button>)}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: All your states updates should happen at root parent component / at store if you are using redux. So that new state will be at place (root component parent) and that updated states will be passed as prop to child component, star component as per current question

Comment: @ShubhamJ. there is no requirement of using redux

Comment: So you can maintain state at your parent component (MovieCard) and pass that to child component (Star). And also callbacks as prop to update the states.
So that state will be maintained only at parent component and it will be passed down to child,

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for your comments. I moved all states and functions to parent class but it didn't helped. Can you help please i am stucked